# A complete Tate Huber ring is Banachizable (maybe not)?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, banach-algebras, p-adic, perfectoid-spaces

I have questions of technical nature.

A complete Tate Huber ring is a complete topological (commutative) ring $A$ admitting an open subring $A_0$ whose topology is the $\varpi A_0$-adic topology, for some $\varpi \in A_0$ which is a unit in $A$.

I think that a Banachizable ring (complete topological ring $A$ whose topology is given by a non-archimedean submultiplicative valuation $| \cdot | : A \to \mathbb{R}^{\times}_{>0} \cup \{ 0 \}$) is a complete Tate Huber ring if and only if there exists a unit $\varpi \in A$ with $| \varpi | < 1$.

Conversely, suppose that $A$ is a complete Tate Huber ring. Fix an open bounded subring $A_0 \subset A$ and a pseudo-uniformizer $\varpi \in A_0$ (as above). I then try to define a submultiplicative valuation $| \cdot | : A \to \mathbb{R}^{\times}_{>0} \cup \{ 0 \}$ by sending $a$ to the infimum of $e^{n/m}$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^m \varpi^n \in A_0$. Then all properties of a submultiplicative valuation seem to be satisfied except $|a+b|\leq sup(|a|,|b|)$.

**Question:** Is the last property satisfied as well, or for some examples it is not satisfied?

Also, supposing that this is satisfied, it seems that the valuation thus-defined is continuous, and if there exists an integrally closed bounded open surbring in $A$, then this valuation defines the topology (so that $A$ becomes Banachizable). In fact, I think that it is enough to have a "radical" subring, i.e. a bounded open subring $A_0 \subset A$ such that $a^m \in A_0 \implies a \in A_0$ for $a \in A, m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$.

**Question:** In a complete Tate Huber ring $A$, does there always exists a "radical" subring (as above)? (if $A$ is uniform, then we can take $A^{\circ}$).

Comment: Go the `\varpi`

Comment: @DavidRoberts Didn't understand the comment.

Comment: `\varpi` ($\varpi$) is not a common symbol to use, nice to see it turn up :-)

Comment: @DavidRoberts Oh, ok :)

Comment: @DavidRoberts I think it is quite common in this context.

Comment: I think now that the question is quite pointless, as one can define a norm on a complete Tate Huber ring simply by $|a|=inf (e^{-n} : \varpi^n a \in A_0)$ - making it Banach